# Can I use AngularJS 'ng-view' in TideSDK 1.3.1beta?

Tags: angularjs, tidesdk

I've got a simple TideSDK application going, using AngularJS. Works nicely.

Recently as I started adding features, I replaced my single `ng-include` with `ng-view` and Angular routing. It works great in Chrome, but errors galore in TideSDK.

Is it possible to use ng-view in an application built with  TideSDK 1.3.1beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the age of the embedded webkit within TideSDK. TideKit is on its way to release quite soon and includes latest webkit for much greater HTML5 compliance. You will be able to migrate your existing code once it is available.

Comment: Thanks @fairwinds. Too late for us, alas; in the 2 weeks since I asked, we've switched over to chromium embedded! Oh well, glad to hear that TideKit is coming along. :/

Comment: @Daryn Happy that you've got a solution, TideKit is much more than a wrapper. Check it out once it is available.